# How to get filtered values of data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find, in a given column `"type"`, the values of that column that repeats `"n"` times.

I did this:

```
n = 5
df = dataf["type"].value_counts() > 5
```

`print(df)` will return something like this:

```
Bike           True
Truck          True
Car            False
```

How to get the values "Bike" and "Car" ? I want to add them in a set.

Comment: Can you show us `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lambda` in a `loc` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"vehicle": ["bike"] * 7 + ["truck"] * 8 + ["car"] * 4})
print(df)
print("\nUsing loc...")
print(df["vehicle"].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 5])
```

gives

```
   vehicle
0     bike
1     bike
2     bike
3     bike
4     bike
5     bike
6     bike
7    truck
8    truck
9    truck
10   truck
11   truck
12   truck
13   truck
14   truck
15     car
16     car
17     car
18     car

Using loc...
truck    8
bike     7
Name: vehicle, dtype: int64
```

Comment: But then how do I extract only the values truck and bike from the series? Thanks!

Comment: `df["vehicle"].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 5].index.tolist()` @jimmy

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
aux = dataf["type"].value_counts()
greater_than_five = aux[aux > 5]
```

The first line get the count of the types and the second line filter for the types that is greater than five.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
n = 5
df = dataf["type"].value_counts()[dataf["type"].value_counts() > n]
print(df)
```

Comment: This will return me `Car    7` . How do I extract only the value `Car` ?

Comment: df = dataf["type"].value_counts()[(dataf["type"].value_counts() > 5) & (dataf["type"].value_counts().index == 'Car')]

Answer (score 1):

the most efficient way is with lambda that @user1717828 wrote it.
another way :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"vehicle": ["bike"] * 7 + ["truck"] * 8 + ["car"] * 4})


df2 = df["vehicle"].agg({'count':'value_counts'})
df2[df2['count'] > 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new columns called counter which contain '1':

```
df['counter'] = 1
```

and use groupby:

```
df = df.groupby(['types']).sum()
df = df[df.counter > n]
```